# Computation on an Euler character

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology

In the Bridgeland's [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0009053v1.pdf) "Flops and derived categories" (proof of (4.6), page 12), he computed an Euler character without much explanation. I thought this might not be difficult (and might not be suitable for this site), but I am not able to get it straight. Here are relevant information (the notation is chosen to be compatible with the paper):

Let $Y$ be a smooth projective threefold. $M \in D(Y)$ is in the (unbounded) derived category of $Y$, and the first chern class $c_1(M) = [D']$, with $D'$ an effective divisor on $Y$. Let $N'$ be a sheaf on $Y$ which is supported on a curve $C'$. Then it is claimed that 
$$\chi(M, N'[1]) = D' \cdot C'.$$

My problem is that I don't know how to compute chern classes of $M$ and $N'$.

Suppose in a oversimplified situation where $M = \mathcal{O}_Y(D')$ and $N'=\mathcal O_{C'}$. Then $$\chi(M, N'[1]) = - \chi(M, N') = - \chi(C', \mathcal O_{C'}(-D')) = C' \cdot D' -1 + g(C'),$$ where $g(C')$ is the genus of $C'$. But this does not match the above claim. Where did I make mistakes?

Comment: Probably, the rank of $M$ is assumed to be 0.

Comment: What do mean by rank? On an open set $U$ of $Y$, this $M$ is exactly the same as $\mathcal O_U(D')$, so I guess the rank should be $1$.

Answer (score 2):

I will use Bridgeland's notation. Since $\Phi$ is an equivalence of categories (by (4.3)), 
$$
\chi(M,N) = 
\chi(\Phi(O_W(D)),\Phi(O_C(-1))) = 
\chi(O_W(D),O_C(-1)).
$$
On the other hand, by adjunction between the pushforward and the pullback (for the embedding $C \hookrightarrow W$), one has
$$
Ext^p(O_W(D),O_C(-1)) = 
Ext^p(O_C(D\vert_C),O_C(-1)) = 
H^p(C,O_C(-D \vert_ C - 1)).
$$
Finally, by Riemann--Roch on the RATIONAL curve $C$ one has 
$$
\chi(O_C(-D\vert_C - 1)) = 
r(O_C(-D\vert_C - 1)) + \deg(O_C(D \cdot C - 1)) =
1 + (- D\cdot C - 1)
$$
which equals $- D \cdot C$.

Comment: Dear Sasha, Thank you very much for your answer! This part is in fact the first claim in Bridgeland's claim, and I could get it as you argued (i.e. use $C$ is a rational curve). What I am asking is the second part of the claim. I did not change Bridgeland's notation except that I use $N'$ instead of $N[-1]$. But when I did the same thing for this part, it no longer works, even in the above oversimplified case.

Comment: Note that the curve $C'$ is rational, and that $Rg_*\circ \Phi = Rf_*$, hence $Rg_*(N') = 0$, so in the "oversimplified case" you should take $N' = O_{C'}(-1)$.